# jQuery - Reload table

Tags: php, jquery, dynamic, reload

I'm trying to reload a table which was also generated by PHP.

The table has an ID: `#bookmarks`

After the user pressed a button, the table should reload the content + the data they have just added. I'm a bit confused because I don't know how to send all of the data from a PHP result.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For specific help using jQuery, check out the [jEditable](http://www.appelsiini.net/projects/jeditable) plugin which is designed to provide the ability to edit data in place.  There's also instructions on how to collect the data and save it.

Answer (score 4):

This is assuming your PHP returns a ready-to-inject HTML code for the table:

```
$("#update_button").click(function(){
    $("#mytable").load("/tools/getTable.php")
})
```

in your page you need a DIV placeholder like this:

```
<div id="mytable"></div>
```

and your getTable.php needs to echo back html like this:

```
<table>
  <tr>
    <td>col1<td>
    <td>col2<td>
  <tr>
</table>
```

Comment: I can't really do that because there are other functions which require the table to be there.

Comment: James but the table will be there, even on the first request, you can do <?PHP include("getTable.php") ?> inside the file and when you open the page your table will be loaded, and using the AJAX it will be fetched dynamically

Answer (score 1):

In point form:

- Submit the user's data back to a PHP page via an AJAX request. (Look at the jQuery Form plugin)
- The PHP page should accept and validate the data, insert it into the database and then send a response back to the page in some format (I recommend JSON, using the php function [json_encode](http://php.net/json_encode).

  - The response should either be a "rejected" or an "accepted" with the user's data returned to them, cleaned up as required by your own system.
- Then in the AJAX success callback method, use jQuery to append the data into the table, or give them a message telling them why it was rejected.

Comment: I don't use JSON to generate my table, I find it an extra step which can be skipped easily.

Comment: so you generate it on the server side in PHP? I don't see there being much difference there, except: a) it's more data to send, and b) you're putting presentation logic (html tags) in your data layer (php).

Answer (score 0):

When the user presses the button you should call the code that was used to load the table.
The data might be the data from the beginning + the data the users added. Or the data might be reretrieved from the server, depending on how your application works.

A bit more info might clear things up, so we could give more specific answers.

Answer (score 0):

Well the table is generated using this:

```
<table id="bookmarks">
        <thead>
            <tr class="table-top">
                <th>Thumbnail</th>
                <th>Title/Description</th>
                <th>Tags</th>
                <th>Action</th>
            </tr>
        </thead>
        <?php
        $hID = userToID($_SESSION['username']);
        $hQuery = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM linkz WHERE userid='$hID'") or die(mysql_error());
        while($hRow = mysql_fetch_array($hQuery)) {
            echo "<tr class='link'><td><img src='http://www.thumbshots.de/cgi-bin/show.cgi?url=".$hRow["location"]."' /></td><td><a href='share/".$hRow['shareid']."'>".$hRow["title"]."</a> - <i>". $hRow["description"]."</i><br /><b>Share Link:</b> http://www.linkbase.us/share/".$hRow['shareid']."</td><td>".$hRow['tags']."</td><td><a href='#' id='".$hRow['shareid']."' class='delbutton'>Delete</a></td></tr>";
        }
    ?>
    </table>
```

Comment: okay, I think you'll need a different way of working if you want to ajaxify your table with jQuery.

Answer (score 0):

You'll need to look into the basics of AJAX first.

You'll need to learn how to walk before you can start running.

Search for some tutorials on Ajax, PHP & Ajax

[Here](http://www.sitepoint.com/article/ajax-jquery/) and [here](http://viralpatel.net/blogs/2009/04/jquery-ajax-tutorial-example-ajax-jquery-development.html) are 2 to start with

Comment: Everything is entered fine into the table, even deletion works!

What about reloading the whole page? Will location.reload() work even after an AJAX post?

Comment: location.reload() might work. I don't really know that.
So if I'm correct, you are posting the data to the server using ajax. But when retrieving, you don't use ajax. Right?

If you retrieve the data with Ajax, the whole reloading-part might be a load easier, and cleaner than just performing a document.reload()