# Reload table based on POST data

Tags: php, jquery, ajax

I am trying to create a table that would change its content based on user input. The table displays some data from a database; it starts the selection starting with a given calendar date that defaults to current date.
I took a look at [jQuery - Reload table](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/887778/jquery-reload-table).
Then I made a PHP script that generates the table, gentable.php.
When I try using a button with the event:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
 $("#maket").click(function(){
    $("#mytable").load("tablegen.php");
 });
});
```

everithing goes fine(the div mytable is filled with the generated table).
Now I want to send some input data to the PHP script in order to generate the table starting with a different date. This is what I tried:

```
$(document).ready(function() { 
    $('#myform').ajaxForm({ 
       target: '#mytable', 
 success: function() { 
            $("#mytable").load("tablegen.php");
        } 
    }); 
});
```

And added in the PHP script the following lines:

```
if (isset($_POST['textf'])){
    $value = $_POST['textf'];  
}else{
    $value = '2010/11/28';
}

genTable($value);
```

Unfortunatelly, this opens a new page that contains the table with beginning date not modified.
What am I doing wrong?
I also tried using .post but had no successful results. Please help. 
Thanks a lot.
Diana

Comment: Please reformat your code. Look at the "How to format" part when asking a question.

Answer (score 1):

Try the following:

```
$.ajax({
  type: 'POST',
  url: 'gentable.php',
  data: {textf: **INSERT_VALUE_HERE**},
  dataType: 'html',
  success: function(data, txtStatus, xmlHttpReq){
    $('#mytable').html(data);
  }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/

```
$.ajax({
   type: "POST",
   url: "tablegen.php",
   data: "textf=whateveryouwant",
   success: function(msg){
     alert( "Data back: " + msg );
   }
 });
```

Answer (score 0):

Thank you for your answers. For some reason, I didn't manage to use `$.ajax`. Instead, I passed the values I needed to the load function, like this:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
 $("#maket").click(function(){
    $("#mytable").load("gentabel.php", {textf: $('#textf').val()});
 });
});
```

The behavior is what I wanted. :)